# whats the best practice of putting all the API addresses in a service page in Angular

Tags: angular

im new in Angular,
I have a service.js file to call my services to do so :

```
 export class ServiceService {
 data:any;
 url ="http://localhost:59628/api/AcessInfo/";
 url_turlist="http://localhost:59628/api/Reports/turList";
 url_avgWind="http://localhost:59628/api/Reports/avgWind";
 url_productionSum="http://localhost:59628/api/Reports/sumProduction";
```

now i have 5 address if it becomes 30 or more,how should i manage them?all in this single page? i would be gratfeul if anyone explains me the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store them in an `Enum` in a separate file. `URLs.ts` file for example

```
enum URLs {
    AcessInfo = "http://localhost:59628/api/AcessInfo/",
    turList= "http://localhost:59628/api/Reports/turList",
    avgWind= "http://localhost:59628/api/Reports/avgWind",
    sumProduction= "http://localhost:59628/api/Reports/sumProduction"
}
```

Then from your service, use them like this:

```
getAcessInfo(url: string, options?: Object) {
    return this.httpClient.get(environment.apiUrl + URLs.AcessInfo, options);
}
```